# ActionScript Get All Network Activity?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, rtmp, urlrequest

Is there a way within ActionScript 3.0 to:

- Get all URLRequests() that are made within the application?
- Get all RTMP:// connections to a Flash Media server?

Since my application contains SWC files which were compiled by another developer, I cannot directly access the ActionScript which creates the URL requests and RTMP connections.

Thank your for your time.

Comment: in google **chrome** press **F12** then **network** tab no need to install a plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can use a web debugging proxy to monitor all messages that are sent over the wire. I like to use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) because it deserializes AMF messages so that you can read them. It's not free, but you can use it as long as you want anyway. You'll just get an annoying delay every once in a while.
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) has a lot of functionality built-in (even for Flash remoting). Go to the 'Net' panel and you'll see a 'Flash' tab. Your application has to run in the browser for this one though, not just in the standalone debug flash player.
- If you're using FlashBuilder, it has a view called 'Network Monitor' that does the same thing. I still prefer Charles though because it has more features.
- Adobe just released [SWF investigator](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/swfinvestigator/) on Labs, which seems to allow you to take your compiled swc's apart as well as intercepting AMF messages. I can't tell you more since I've never worked with it. (props to @Eduardo for this one)

Comment: Oh! I never knew Firebug could profile Flash applications. Good to know! Thank you!

Comment: You might want to add 'SWF Investigator' to the list of tools to check out (just posted in the Adoble Labs site); it looks promising