# Developer tools or Firebug equivalent for Flash / Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, debugging, streaming, developer-tools, flash-media-server

For web applications, we can use Chrome Developer tools or Firebug to debug / monitor the application.

Is there any way to debug a Flash application from the browser?

One specific thing that I would like to debug are the network calls made from the Flash component to the server. For music streaming, I would like to get the streaming URL for example.

Comment: If you're using Adobe Media Server, it has built-in logging that includes information regarding network calls

Comment: I do not have access to the server, only the client in the browser

Comment: Firebug allegedly has flash debugging options. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584490/actionscript-get-all-network-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adobe SWF investigator](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/swfinvestigator.html) for that. I don't know if you will have everything you need, but it will give you some insights